# AttributeError: 'character' object has no attribute 'set_name'

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror

I get the following Error in Python:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 7, in 
char.set_name(input())
AttributeError: 'character' object has no attribute 'set_name'

I have no clue why,

Here is my code
(function defined in a several file)

```
class character:
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = None
    self.gender = None
    self.race = None
    self.lp = None
    self.ap = None
#Name
def set_name(self, name):
  self.name = name
#Gender
def set_gender(self, gender):
  if gender in ["m","f"]:
    self.gender = gender
  else:
    print("Please select your gender by typing m for male and f for female")
#Race
def set_race(self, race):
  self.race = race
  if race == "Human":
    self.lp = 9
    self.ap = 2
  elif race == "Elve":
    self.lp = 8
    self.ap = 3
  elif race == "Orc":
    self.lp = 10
    self.ap = 1
  else:
    print("Sorry, you only can choose between Human, Elve and Orc")
```

My main.py so far,

```
from Classes.character import character
from functions.yesorno import _yesorno
#character
char = character()
while True:
  print("please enter a name for your character")
  char.set_name(input())
  print("Your name is: " + char.name + ". Are you happy with your choice? Type 'y' for yes, 'n' for no.")
  if _yesorno(input()):
    break
  else:
    next
```

Comment: Are you sure the indentation is correct?

Comment: I didn't see an indentation error, do you ?

Comment: `set_name` looks to be out of the `class`, try adding spaces

Comment: Not seeing an indentation error doesn't mean that the indentation is correct. Indent your `character` methods (e.g. `set_name` and `set_gender`) inside the `class` block.

Comment: .... oh man, just in the second after i submited my answer I saw it. Thanks mate!

Comment: My first out of a learning book program ... it will be a small text based role play game ! :)thanks @HenryHarutyunyan

Comment: @e.nice no worries, have a great journey in programming